# error messages were produced once only

Tags: jquery

i have the below jQuery code to check the start and end dates , but the error message shows once only and if the user changed the end date with any wrong values no error messages were produced. is there something i'm missing ?

```
$('input[name="endDate"]').change(function(){
    var startDate=$('input[name="startDate"]');
    var endDate=$('input[name="endDate"]');
    var errorSpan= $('.errorSpan');
    $.ajax({
        url:'${createLink(controller:'empRef', action: 'checkServiceDatesAjax')}'   ,
        type:'POST' ,
        data:{startDate:startDate.val(), endDate:endDate.val()} ,
        success: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        },

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest,  textStatus,  errorThrown) { 
            errorSpan.html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='red'>"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"</font>").fadeOut(5000);
            endDate.focus();

        }
    })

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you call `fadeOut()` on the error message container, it sets its `display` property to `none`. When you try to reuse the same element, it is already hidden. You can make it work by ensuring the element is visible before fading it out:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest,  textStatus,  errorThrown) { 
  errorSpan.html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color='red'>"+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"</font>")
  errorSpan.show()
  errorSpan.fadeOut(5000);
  endDate.focus();
}
```